# End two alarm signals in Unix and count SIGINT

Tags: c++, linux

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
using namespace std;

int count = 0; 

void alarm2(int signo)
{
    cout << count;
}

void alarm1(int signo)
{
    signal(SIGALRM, alarm2);
    cout << "ctrl+C";
    alarm(10);
    sleep(10);
}

int main()
{
    signal(SIGALRM, alarm1);

    alarm(3);
    sleep(5);
}
```

I want that after 3 seconds I get the message "ctrl+C" and then another alarm set for 10 seconds; after that I should get the value of `count`. But when I run after just 10 sec I get "ctrl+C" and the value of `count`.

Comment: Use pause(), don't tag C#, don't use cout in signal handler.

Comment: why should i not use cout and where i use pause()

Comment: You aren't sending a newline after your `cout` call, and you aren't explicitly flushing the output... you only see the output later because your program terminates causing the buffer to flush. Furthermore, the sleep within your first signal handler is a terrible thing to do; get rid of it! (Perhaps move it into main).

Comment: I didn't find any link for c++ but you may get an idea from this [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16891019/how-to-avoid-using-printf-in-a-signal-handler) in C

Comment: i have move sleep to main still no progress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example you made many, many mistakes.

First of all look at documentation about which function is safe to call from
signal handlers:
https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/SIG30-C.+Call+only+asynchronous-safe+functions+within+signal+handlers

Of course functions that can allocate memory is not safe to call, because of it is not safe to call malloc.
Because of it is not right to call printf or std::ostream::opeartor<< (std::cout <<) in signal handler.

Second, in documentation (type man 3 sleep) clearly written **it is not safe mix sleep and alarm**,

Third you not wait enough in main function, so it can exit before the second alarm handler run.

Here is how it can be done:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>

volatile sig_atomic_t done = 0;

void alarm2(int signo)
{
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, "alarm2\n", sizeof("alarm2\n") - 1);
    done = 1;
}

void alarm1(int signo)
{
  signal(SIGALRM, alarm2);
  write(STDOUT_FILENO, "ctrl+C\n", sizeof("ctrl+C\n") - 1);
  alarm(10);
}

int main()
{
  signal(SIGALRM, alarm1);

  alarm(3);

  while (done == 0)
    sleep(1); //sleep can be wake up by alarm signal, so check flag    
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much now i have completed my work by adding your precautions.

Comment: @UsmanNazir Please click the checkmark next to this answer and upvote it. It helps a lot.

Comment: sure I will vote it later as i cannot vote due to newer.it do not allow me to do so

Comment: @UsmanNazir **No**,  0x499602D2's means [you may like to accept an answer but click right](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Answer (score 0):

Add "<< endl;" to all your cout statements and try again.

Comment: i am afraid still nothing happened